# AWK - print lines in the loop?

Tags: for-loop, awk

I have this command:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{c="1"; for(i=NF; i<9; i++) print c++, "_"}'
1 _
2 _
3 _
4 _
5 _
6 _
7 _
8 _
9 _
```

I want this command to print the result:

```
1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
3 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
4 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
5 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
6 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
7 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
8 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
9 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk '
  BEGIN { 
    for (i=0; i<9; ++i) {
      printf("%d",i+1);
      for (j=0; j<9; ++j) {
        printf(" _");
      }
      printf("\n");
    }
  }
'
```

Answer (score 2):

This is similar to Vaughn's answer, but might be a little faster if that's important.

```
awk 'BEGIN { str = ""; for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) str = str" _";
             for (i = 1; i <= 9; i++) printf("%d%s\n", i, str) }'
```

Answer (score 1):

Why bother writing code for generating a small, simple piece of text?

You already have the output you want, because you typed it out. Just use that piece of text.

The following shell script is derived directly from your expected output:

```
cat <<EOF
1 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
2 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
3 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
4 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
5 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
6 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
7 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
8 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
9 _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
EOF
```